Azure DevOps - Branch Merge triggering 2 Instances of Pipeline
My repo ("z4") has 2 pipeline yamls.
When I merge into "m_dev" branch I want to run "dev.yaml"
When I merge into "m_release" branch I want to run "release.yaml"
dev.yaml
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - m_dev

release.yaml
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - m_release

I have set my Pipelines up thus :

Repo = "z4"
Branch = "m_dev"
Pipeline Path = "/.pipelines/dev.yaml"


Repo = "z4"
Branch = "m_release"
Pipeline Path = "/.pipelines/release.yaml"

Pipeline for Dev works as expected.
However, when I merge into m_release, I end up with 2 instances on my release pipeline running.
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong ?
Thanks

Do the triggered two runs of release pipeline run for the same commit? And do they have the same trigger type? Provide the screenshots of the summary pages for the two runs.

Yes & Yes. I did find the issue - kind of. The branch was created in the Web UI of AZDO. If I create the branch locally from VSCode, then there is no problem.
Currently looking into further to try and present a clear case.....

Can you provide the detailed steps and related screenshots to show how to reproduce the issue? @SiBush
